# How do I open this in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I came across this project online and can't really get it to open with Visual Studio. Extremely new to Visual Studio. This doesn't have an exact project file that can be opened from what I've understood. It has a bunch of .cs and .aspx.cs files. How exactly do I open and execute this project in Visual Studio? Or am I barking up the wrong tree and trying to open something that can't be opened?

Link to the project - http://www.speedyshare.com/98XZf/ca-ma-sy

Comment: you would want to open a `.csproj` or `.sln` file. if there isn't one, you might need to create a new empty solution and add everything to a new project yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the project into a new empty project on Visual Studio. I have two files for each page, a .aspx and a .aspx.cs. Once I copy the .aspx file, there's only a .aspx.vb file being generated and not a .aspx.cs. How do I change it?

Answer (score 1):

May  be your project is not a web application project. it might be wesite.
If it is web application you will find .csproj file, if you didn't find then  just follow the below steps

1. Open Visual Studio
2. click on file --> Open --> Website
3. You will get dialogue box with local file structure, Just Navigate to your    project folder and select and click on open, After click on open your solution will be ready with your project.

Cheers,
Vijay